# How to read tiff files of size 3 GB in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, bufferedimage, tiff, jai

Currently I am working on an image processing project in which I need to extract features from the tiff images of size 3 to 4 GB.
I tried reading the file using BufferedImage and ImageIO, but tif format is not supported by them and thus null exception gets thrown.
I then tried it using JAI but I am unable to read the file and same null exception is thrown.
Hipi does not support Tiff format.
I am stuck and any suggestion as to how i should read the file is welcomed.

Comment: You can use my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) library to read TIFF files. But I'm not sure if files that size can be read into memory, due to Java array size limits...

Comment: While trying to build the mvn package, I am getting this error: [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
**[FATAL]** Non-resolvable parent POM for com.twelvemonkeys:twelvemonkeys:3.4-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:9 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Temporary failure in name resolution and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 13

Comment: Fist of all, you shouldn't need to build the project, you should be able to just depend on the latest (currently 3.3.2) version. I don't have a problem checking out a clean copy and build locally, so it seems you have experienced a network issue (the error message says "Temporary failure in name resolution", which could be a DNS issue, and it could be that it works if you just try again). But as said above, you shouldn't have to build in the first place.

Comment: PS: The artifact in question, is [this POM](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/9/oss-parent-9.pom), and it works fine from here.